# Pass form Variables into argument

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a webform(below), i would like to pass the form variables into a function.

I would like to once user clicks submit the username and password are passed into a site login function:

```
   $.ajax( { 
            url: "http://microsubs.risk.net/microsub.php",
            method: 'GET',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == 1) {$('#rdm-below-header').append('<div id=\"modal\" class=\"modalStyle\">' +

                        '<div>' +

                        '<button type=\"button\" id=\"close\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"modal\" aria-label=\"close\"><span aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</span></button><br>' +

                          '<div id=\"titleText\" style=\" text-align:center; font-size: 24px; margin-top: 15px;\">Fill in your details for 24hr access to Risk.net</div><br>' +


                         '<form id=\"microsubs_form\"  style=\"text-align:center; clear:both\" >' +

                            '<input type=\"text\" id=\"ms_firstName\" name=\"ms_firstName\" required placeholder=\"First Name\" style=\"float:left;\" >'  +

                            '<input type=\"text\" id=\"ms_lastName\" name=\"ms_lastName\" required style=\"float:left; margin-left:20px;\" placeholder=\"Last Name\">' +

                            '<input type=\"email\" id=\"ms_email\" name=\"ms_email\" required placeholder=\"Corporate Email address\" pattern=\"^.*(\*barclays|\*barcap).*$\" oninvalid=\"this.setCustomValidity(\'Please enter your corporate email\')\" style=\"float:left; margin-top: 10px;\">' +

                            '<input type=\"password\" id=\"ms_password\" name=\"ms_password\" required style=\"clear:right; margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 20px;\" placeholder=\"Password\" pattern=\".{6,}\">' +

                            '<input class=\"cls_redirect\" id=\"redirect_url\" name=\"redirect_url\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"http://www.risk-responsive.nginx.incbase.net/\">' +



                            '<input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit-form\"  class=\"btn.login\" name=\"submit\" style=\"alignment-adjust:central; margin-top:30px; clear:right;\" ><br>' +

                        '</form>' +



                         '<div style=\"text-align:center; clear: both; font-size: 16px; margin-top: 5px; \"><br>'  +

                          'If you already have a subscription, <a href=\"login\">sign in here.</a>' +



                         '</div>' +

                     '</div>' +

                    '</div>');
                }
                  console.log(data);
                $('#submit-form').on('click', function(){
                    formSubmit();
                })


             },

             error: function(error) {
                 console.log(error);
             }

        } );


// Bind to the submit event of our form


function formSubmit(){
  $("#microsubs_form").submit(function(event){

 var request;

//
var userName = ms_email;
var userPwd = ms_password;

    // Abort any pending request
    if (request) {
        request.abort();
    }
    // setup some local variables
    var $form = $(this);

    // Let's select and cache all the fields
    var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");

    // Serialize the data in the form
    var serializedData = $form.serialize();


    // Disabled form elements will not be serialized.
    $inputs.prop("disabled", true);

    // Fire off the request to /form.php
  request = $.ajax({
        url: "http://microsubs.risk.net/ms_form_handler.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: serializedData,
        success: function(data){
             console.log(data);
             $("#rdm-below-header").hide();

            siteLogin(userName, userPwd, 'http://www.risk-responsive.nginx.incbase.net/')
        },
        error: function(error) {
                 console.log(error);
             },
    });

    // Prevent default posting of form
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

In the Ajax there is the success:

```
 **siteLogin(username here, password here, 'http://www.risk-responsive.nginx.incbase.net/')**
```

The username and password created by the user in the form should go in here.

I have tried to add it like below:

```
 var userName = ms_email;
  var userPwd = ms_password;
```

However this is not working so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: did u try `var userName = $('#ms_email').val()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add them like this:

```
var userName = ms_email.value;
var userPwd = ms_password.value;
```